# Securing Non-MVC pages in an ASP.MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a site this is almost all in MVC 3 but I do have one section (~\Reports) that is written in WebForms.  I have forms authentication set up in the web.config. In the MVC code I use the [Authorize] attribute.  All of the MVC stuff is secured correctly but I can navigate directly to the Report folder and it won't redirect me to the login page.

How can I secure the Reports folder so that it works the same as the rest of my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Reports folder add a new Web.Config file that has only this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```